# PostgreSQL Reversed ILIKE on column name

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, sql-like

I am trying to figure out the given **username** by frontend is a valid name or not. 
I have a table that contains lot of names.
So for example I got **Adam18** I need to give an answer in real time (< 500ms)

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE 'Adam18' ILIKE '%' || name || '%'
```

The query is correct but it uses sequential scan

Explain result:

```
Seq Scan on names  (cost=0.00..2341.20 rows=527 width=516) (actual time=1.452..24.774 rows=12 loops=1)
    Filter: ('Adam18'::text ~~ (('%'::text || (name)::text) || '%'::text))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 105314
  Buffers: shared hit=498
Planning time: 0.062 ms
Execution time: 24.796 ms
```

Is there a way to create index on this case?

My current index:

```
CREATE INDEX names_gin_idx ON names USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
```

I cannot use this. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes I did it, there are 105 326 rows in the table

Comment: Those 24ms are already way below the required 500ms ;)  But I think trigram indexes can only be used in the "other directory", e.g. `where name ilike '%Adam18%'` Full text search might be an alternative

Comment: I guess its faster now than I tried first time, because of the cache.
What kind of index do you suggest on **ILike** instead of full text search?

Comment: As I said: I don't think you can support _that_ condition with an index (only the "other way round")